# How to view PPT from Listview in Android

Tags: android, listview, powerpoint

**My Fragment Activity**

```
public class MessagesFragment extends Fragment {
    ListView lv_pdf;
    public static ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
    PPTAdapter obj_adapter;
    public static int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 1;
    boolean boolean_permission;
    File dir;
    public MessagesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_via_mobile_ppt, container, false);
        lv_pdf = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_pdf);
init();
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }
    public void init() {


        dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
        fn_permission();


        lv_pdf.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
//                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PPt.class);
//                intent.putExtra("position", i);
//                startActivity(intent);
//
//                Log.e("Position", i + "");
                File file = new File(dir.toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            }
        });
    }

    public ArrayList<File> getfile(File dir) {
        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    getfile(listFile[i]);

                } else {

                    boolean booleanpdf = false;
                    if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".ppt")) {

                        for (int j = 0; j < fileList.size(); j++) {
                            if (fileList.get(j).getName().equals(listFile[i].getName())) {
                                booleanpdf = true;
                            } else {

                            }
                        }

                        if (booleanpdf) {
                            booleanpdf = false;
                        } else {
                            fileList.add(listFile[i]);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return fileList;
    }


    private void fn_permission() {
        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

            if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))) {


            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);

            }
        } else {
            boolean_permission = true;

            getfile(dir);

            obj_adapter = new PPTAdapter(getContext(), fileList);
            lv_pdf.setAdapter(obj_adapter);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS) {

            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                boolean_permission = true;
                getfile(dir);

                obj_adapter = new PPTAdapter(getContext(), fileList);
                lv_pdf.setAdapter(obj_adapter);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please allow the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }




    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

**My Adapter Activity**

```
public class PPTAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<File> {


    Context context;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    ArrayList<File> al_pdf;

    public PPTAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<File> al_pdf) {
        super(context, R.layout.adapter_pdf, al_pdf);
        this.context = context;
        this.al_pdf = al_pdf;

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        if (al_pdf.size() > 0) {
            return al_pdf.size();
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {


        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_pdf, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tv_filename = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        }

        viewHolder.tv_filename.setText(al_pdf.get(position).getName());

        return view;

    }

    public class ViewHolder {

        TextView tv_filename;


    }

}
```

I want to open the `PPT` after it is being listed in my `ListView`.The listing of the `PPT` works fine but how to open it from the item of `ListView` I am stucked in this situation. Used the code as mentioned in `onitemclicklistener` of `ListView`.

And I got one PPT Viewer Library from [here](https://github.com/itsrts/pptviewer-android) but I don't know that how to use it in Android Studio as it is for Ecllipse.

Comment: you are just giving the path to the directory not the file path

Comment: Sir I gave the path of file like this File file = new File(dir.toString()+"/"+fileList.get(position).getName()); but still it does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

Change the code from this

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

to

```
startActivity(intent);
```

This will show the user options about any power-point viewers that they have installed and they can pick one.